# Trying to disable device access through OS X kext with a higher probe score

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension, facetime

I need to disable access to certain devices (the built-in FaceTime Camera, for example), and have been trying to do so by providing a simple kext with a higher probe score than what is currently attached.

My kext matches and attaches to the camera as both IOProviderClass `IOUSBInterface` and IOProviderClass `IOUSBDevice`, but all of the original kexts still attach to it as well.  This is how it looks in IORegistryExplorer:

```
FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)@14700000   # USB device
+-- FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)@0      # USB interface
|   +-- FaceTimeDisabler                 # my kext matching as IOUSBInterface
|   +-- IOUSBInterfaceUserClientV3       # original
+-- IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2              # original
+-- IOUSBInterface@1                     # original
|   +-- IOUSBInterfaceUserClientV3       # original
+-- IOUSBInterface@2                     # original
+-- FaceTimeDisabler                     # my kext matching as IOUSBDevice
```

I thought the point of device and driver matching was to select a single kext to attach to the device, so I expected that if my kext matched with the highest probe score, it would gain exclusive control of the device, but that clearly isn't the case.

My questions are these:

1. How can I ensure that my kext gains exclusive access to a device?
2. If there is a better approach to disable access to a device, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to claim exclusive access to a USB device or interface, you will need to `open()` the nub object, specifying the `kUSBOptionBitOpenExclusivelyMask` bit in the `options` argument.

So in your `FaceTimeDisabler`'s `start()` method, do something like:

```
IOUSBNub* usb_provider = OSDynamicCast(IOUSBNub, provider);
if (usb_provider == nullptr)
{
  IOLog("FaceTimeDisabler: Provider is not USB nub\n");
  return false;
}

bool got_exclusive_access = usb_provider->open(this, kUSBOptionBitOpenExclusivelyMask);
this->opened = got_exclusive_access;
if (!got_exclusive_access)
{
  IOLog("FaceTimeDisabler: failed to acquire exclusive access to camera USB device/interface.\n");
  return false;
}
```

And then in your `stop()` method, make sure you make the corresponding `close()` call if **and only if** the `open()` succeeded (`this->opened` is true in the above example).

Note that the `kUSBOptionBitOpenExclusivelyMask` flag only works for the USB family, even though `open()` exists everywhere. On `IOPCIDevice` objects, exclusivity is implicit in the `open()`, so don't pass the USB exclusive bit when you're trying to block access to PCI-based FaceTime cameras, but do call `open`/`close`. (My 2015 13" rMBP's camera is PCI based - vendor ID `0x14e4`, device ID `0x1570`, class code `04 80 00`)

Comment: Works beautifully.  Noted on kUSBOptionBitOpenExclusivelyMask pertaining only to USB devices.